# Kubernetes ingress controller expose to specific port

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

My institution has firewall settings that block most of the external ports, currently, I have internal Linux virtual machine, for example, **http://abc.xyz:5555** (this link can only be accessed in the internal network), and a Netscaler is set up by the admin so that the internal link is forward to a  publicly available link: **https://def.edu**.

Now I have multiple web servers that use ports like 5556,5557,5558. I want to set up Kubernetes ingress that all traffic goes into the ingress controller first, and the ingress will forward traffic to my multiple web services. Typically as the below image shows. 
[image: Objective]

I only have port 5555 available, but all tutorials of Ingress seem only to support HTTP 80 and HTTPS 443 port. My question is, can I set up the Ingress controller host as **http://abc.xyz:5555**? Or I should go for other approaches, like this said: [`An Ingress does not expose arbitrary ports or protocols. Exposing services other than HTTP and HTTPS to the internet typically uses a service of type Service.Type=NodePort or Service.Type=LoadBalancer.`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/), if so, what terms/techniques should I use?

Comment: What ingress controller are you using and how are you deploying it?

Comment: It was following tutorials on Kubernetes.io so it was nginx.ingress. I'm now trying to switch to Traefik.

Comment: Either deployment can be customised. The http and https ports will be in ingress Service spec. e.g. `kc get service -n ingress nginx-ingress-controller -o yaml`. The note you linked is more in relation to setting arbitrary ports per ingress definition.

Comment: Thanks, I can set deployment ports in ingress.yaml, however, I was looking for a way to set the specific port of the host.

Comment: The host port comes from that service definition. The service is either a load balancer and inherits from the http `port` setting. Or it's a straight Nodeport service, and you can set the `nodePort` to 5555.  Then all your ingress definitions will be accessible on 5555.

Comment: a node port is a bit more difficult as kubernetes also needs to allow 5555 in the `--service-node-port-range` - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport

Comment: How to access the minikube outside the ssh? When I use```minikube service traefik``` I can curl the internal IP```curl http://172.17.0.3:31650```,  since the server has a public IP ```a.b.c.d```, how can I access the kubernetes service using ```a.b.c.d``` IP?

Comment: I tried add result from ```minikube ip``` to /etc/hosts, but the host still only works inside the ssh terminal and I cannot access it from my browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use an ingress, since each loadbalancer gets an own external ip assigned. You can specify a custom port and protocols (tcp,udp,http). I worked with nginx, but the documentation seemed outdated (last checked last week). So we are currently using [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/providers/kubernetes-ingress/). The web dashboard was also a big help in debugging it.

How we solved it:

1. Install traefik via helm with custom values, so it listens to other ports besides 80 and 443; Add custom entrypoints in your [values.yaml](https://github.com/containous/traefik-helm-chart/blob/master/traefik/values.yaml) and install traefik with:
   `helm install --values values.yaml stable/traefik`
2. Install your ingress http/tcp/udp routes
3. Forward your web dashboard and go to http://localhost:9000/dashboard

Please see the official docs for more detailed steps: https://docs.traefik.io/getting-started/install-traefik/#use-the-helm-chart

Comment: Thanks! I have built ingress with traefik. However, I can only access the server by manually run a ```kubectl port-forward --address 10.2.3.4 service/traefik 5555:5555 -n default```.  ```10.2.3.4``` is the internal IP of my server and a domain is configured with this IP. Do you know any options can perform the similar port-forward function in Traefik?

Comment: So your problem is, that your kubernetes cluster is running on a server, but the cluster is not reachable from outside the server? But you can reach the cluster and its services if you are on said server?

Comment: Yes, I have to login an VPN first, then I can ssh into the 10.2.3.4 and access 10.2.3.4 through the browser. The server has a public address https://def.edu -> directs to 10.2.3.4:5555

Comment: If you see an entrypoint with port 5555 in your dashboard, it should be reachable from outside. If not, this is not a traefik problem, but may be of a higher layer. I would create a new question for this, so others will also take a look ;)

Comment: Is this sorted out? i got same issue.